# ByteArrayOutputStream throwing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to read a byte array of an image using the following code but it throws an out of memory exception. I have commented where the exception occurs.

```
byte[] bBuffer = new byte[300000]; // 
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(300000);
int total = 0;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try
{
    int read = 0;           
    while ((dis.read(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.length)) != -1) {
        baos.write(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.length); // Exception occurs here        
        Log.d("outputImageBytes", "Reading Image Bytes: " + bBuffer.length + " " + read++ );
    }
    //baos.flush();
}
catch (Exception e)
{   
    Log.e("outputImageBytes", "Exception Occured while reading image bytes: " + e.getMessage());
    e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the value of `dis.read(..)` when writing to `baos`. It returns the actual number of bytes read, now you are always inserting the total length of the buffer.

Comment: a bit confused mark, can you give me an example please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring that how much number of bytes are actually read.

```
int numberofBytesRead=dis.read(bBuffer, 0, bBuffer.length);
baos.write(bBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: yeah I did this before but it still goes in to an OutOfMemoryError

Comment: the problem may be that we are reading and writing on same byte array.

Comment: yeah thats a mistake i have done. but even after changing it causes the same problem